# EMacs jump to another file

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs for quite sometime. I wanted to know if the currently opened file has some file location e.g. ./acd/tezt.txt, how can we jump to that file immediately using some shortcut?

I think it can be done in VI using CTRL+G. Is there a similar way to do this in emacs?

Comment: I don't understand. if the file is currently opened, why do you want to jump to it?

Comment: @torazaburo I assume they mean that if the open file has some text `./acd/tezt.txt` in it they'd like to be able to jump to that file.

Comment: Yes, what I am trying is suppose file a.txt is currently opened and it has text say "abc.txt" . if my cursor is over this "abc.txt", i am looking for the simplest way to jump to this file if that exists

Comment: You want [`find-file-at-point`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/FFAP.html).

Comment: Thanks Steve. That was exactly what I was looking for